# Notepad++: how to setup a shortcut to enable/disable a preference option

Tags: notepad++, shortcuts

I want to use a shortcut to enable/disable Preferences -> MISC. -> File Status Auto-Detection.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with 3rd party utility if you can give some to its installation and then setup of solution you need.

See [answer to question "In notepad++ change tab size instantly"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22880354/2392157), where another Notepad++ setting was made changeable by keyboard shortcut.

The only thing you need to modify is "path" to your setting (*File Status Auto-Detection*) instead of path to setting *Tab Size*. By path I mean keystrokes and mouse clicks leading to displaying and changing the setting.

Perhaps test the original solution first and then, if you can see how it works, add a keystroke to change your setting.

This way, you can bind changing of almost any setting (or similar action) to keyboard shortcut of your choice. In any application, not only in Notepad++.